# How to fill multiple areas with different colours in a map & adding labels so as not overlapping each other in R?

Tags: r

This is a follow up question to an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377901/how-to-fill-individual-states-on-a-map-in-r).

I have been able to get most of the way to the answer thanks to some help. But still trying to get the fill function to work correctly. I would like to have each PADD in the data set a different colour. A PADD is made up of a number of states.

Here would be the data:

```
structure(list(STATE = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), .Label = c("ALABAMA", "ALASKA", 
"ARIZONA", "ARKANSAS", "CALIFORNIA", "COLORADO", "CONNECTICUT", 
"DELAWARE", "FLORIDA", "GEORGIA", "HAWAII", "IDAHO", "ILLINOIS", 
"INDIANA", "IOWA", "KANSAS", "KENTUCKY", "LOUISIANA", "MAINE", 
"MARYLAND", "MASSACHUSETTS", "MICHIGAN", "MINNESOTA", "MISSISSIPPI", 
"MISSOURI", "MONTANA", "NEBRASKA", "NEVADA", "NEW HAMPSHIRE", 
"NEW JERSEY", "NEW MEXICO", "NEW YORK", "NORTH CAROLINA", "NORTH DAKOTA", 
"OHIO", "OKLAHOMA", "OREGON", "PENNSYLVANIA", "RHODE ISLAND", 
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "TENNESSEE", "TEXAS", "UTAH", 
"VERMONT", "VIRGINIA", "WASHINGTON", "WEST VIRGINIA", "WISCONSIN", 
"WYOMING"), class = "factor"), State = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", 
"Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", 
"Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", 
"Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", 
"New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", 
"Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", 
"South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
"Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
"Wyoming"), class = "factor"), StateAbbreviation = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 
33L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 27L, 28L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 48L, 50L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IA", 
"ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", 
"MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", 
"OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", 
"VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), PADD = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("PAD IV", "PADD I", "PADD II", "PADD III", 
"PADD V"), class = "factor"), SubAreaInPADD = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Sub A", "Sub B", "Sub C"), class = "factor"), 
SubAreaInPADDName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "Central Atlantic", "Lower Atlantic", "New England"
), class = "factor"), PADDName = structure(c(2L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("East Coast", "Gulf Coast", "MidWest", 
"Rocky Mountain", "West Coast"), class = "factor"), RMapClassName = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L), .Label = c("", "alabama", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", 
"colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia", 
"idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", 
"louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts:main", "michigan:north", 
"michigan:south", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", 
"montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", 
"new mexico", "new york:long island", "new york:main", "north carolina:main", 
"north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", 
"rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", "tennessee", 
"texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia:main", "washington:main", 
"west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming"), class = "factor")), .Names =     c("STATE", 
"State", "StateAbbreviation", "PADD", "SubAreaInPADD", "SubAreaInPADDName", 
"PADDName", "RMapClassName"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-52L))
```

My current code:

```
Location<- "C:/"
FileName<-"StatesPADDs.csv"
PADDS<- read.csv(file=paste(Location, FileName, sep=""))
PADDS<-subset(PADDS, State != "Alaska")
PADDS<-subset(PADDS, State != "Hawaii")


PADD_Names<-unique(PADDS$PADDName)

map("state", interior = FALSE)
PADD1<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD I")
PADD2<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD II")
PADD3<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD III")
PADD4<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD IV")
PADD5<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD V")

map('state', region = PADD1$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="red", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD2$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="green", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD3$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="blue", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD4$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="yellow", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD5$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="purple", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states

map.text("state", regions=PADDS$RMapClassName, labels=as.character(PADDS$StateAbbreviation), add=TRUE) #add labels
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the data file causing an error on the fill. But the labels are still unreadable.

PADD4<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PAD IV")

I did not know the function below would fill the full map if PADD4 had no data.

```
map('state', region = PADD4$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="yellow", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)
```

Now add the labels:

```
 map.text("state", regions=PADDS$RMapClassName, labels=as.character(PADDS$StateAbbreviation), add=TRUE) #add labels
```

Answer (score 0):

The coloring problem occurs at this step:

```
PADD4<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD IV")
```

It should have been:

```
PADD4<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PAD IV")  # since you misspelled that value in the data
```

Fixing that prevents the over-coloring of the regional colors that were otherwise briefly visible at the console. The Region labels are a different issue. Take a look at the values for `PADDS$RMapClassName`. They do *not* have any reasonable interpretation as a "region" value. Perhaps you were not trying at this stage to label with a region designator?

```
> str(PADDS)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ STATE            : Factor w/ 50 levels "ALABAMA","ALASKA",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 ...
 $ State            : Factor w/ 50 levels "Alabama","Alaska",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 ...
 $ StateAbbreviation: Factor w/ 50 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 2 4 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 13 ...
 $ PADD             : Factor w/ 5 levels "PAD IV","PADD I",..: 4 5 4 5 1 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ SubAreaInPADD    : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Sub A","Sub B",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 1 ...
 $ SubAreaInPADDName: Factor w/ 4 levels "","Central Atlantic",..: 1 1 1 1 1 4 2 3 3 1 ...
 $ PADDName         : Factor w/ 5 levels "East Coast","Gulf Coast",..: 2 5 2 5 4 1 1 1 1 4 ...
 $ RMapClassName    : Factor w/ 51 levels "","alabama","arizona",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I just noticed that error. I will try to look into solutions for labelling.

Comment: I have tried ` map.text("state", regions=PADDS$RMapClassName, labels=as.character(PADDS$StateAbbreviation, move=TRUE), add=TRUE)' But still the labels are not readable. I would be happy to have them off the map and connected by a line to the state. Is there a function which can do this?

Comment: I'm confused. I see labels within the states. You do not?

Comment: I do but they are basically not readable for the states on the east coast.

Comment: Then pick which ones you don't like, don't print them , and then use `text` and `segments` or `arrows` to draw lines to the state interiors.